# My php cookie session code displays a blank white page no matter what?

Tags: php, html, session

So on one page my users check a box and type agree in an input field to proceed to the next page, I am trying to use session cookies to stop people bypassing this by typing the URL however when you proceed to the next page it just displays blank? i have tried tests such as using Echo to display text at the beginning of the script and have enabled error reporting but the page still just displays white? any ideas why?

Check Box and Input Page php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["terms"])&&isset($_POST["agree"])) {
$agree = $_POST["agree"];
$validated = false;
if($agree=="agree") $validated = true;
if($validated) {
setcookie("agree",($agree));
header("Location: nextpgae");
} else {
header("Location: homepage");
}
}
?>
```

Page it leads to that is displaying blank's php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$validated = false;
if(isset($_COOKIE["agree"])){
$agree = $_COOKIE["agree"];
if(&$agree==("agree")) $validated = true;
}
if($validated) {
} else {
header("Location: homepage");
?>
```

Comment: You are missing a `}`, and that `&` is invalid. Keep in mind: setting the error reporting or display_errors setting in a file with parse errors itself does _nothing_ (no code will be interpreted). Set them higher on: in .htacces. php.ini. or webserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

A blank page is usually symptomatic of a server error. Frequently, it indicates a syntax error in your PHP code. Your server error log will tell you exactly what is going on, but in this case you have missed a closing `}` after this line

```
header("Location: homepage");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement tokens for this kind of procedure. This may help you: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/58268-form-tokens-with-php/